# Spring boot for Micrometer registers filter in nested Prometheus registry not Global which is ignored during metric creation?

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am trying to add a filter for reactive flows:

```
metrics()
```

Registering it with IoC successfully:

```
public class FluxMetricsFilter implements MeterFilter {
    private FluxMetricsConfigurationProperties fluxMetricsConfigurationProperties;

    public FluxMetricsFilter(FluxMetricsConfigurationProperties fluxMetricsConfigurationProperties) {
        this.fluxMetricsConfigurationProperties = fluxMetricsConfigurationProperties;
    }

    public DistributionStatisticConfig configure(Id id, DistributionStatisticConfig config) {
       ....
    }
}
```

The filter gets registered in Prometheus registry, but when the metric is hit while using `metrics()` it doesn't use Prometheus registry but the global one, Spring Boot doesn't register the filter on global level:

[image]

So when I get to `getOrCreateMeter` method my filter list is empty:
[image]

I can see that `metrics()` calls:

```
FluxMetrics(Flux<? extends T> flux) {
    this(flux, null);
}

/**
 * For testing purposes.
 *
 * @param registry the registry to use, or null for global one
 */
FluxMetrics(Flux<? extends T> flux, @Nullable MeterRegistry registry) {
    super(flux);

    this.name = resolveName(flux);
    this.tags = resolveTags(flux, DEFAULT_TAGS_FLUX, this.name);

    if (registry == null) {
        this.registryCandidate = Metrics.globalRegistry;
    }
    else {
        this.registryCandidate = registry;
    }
}
```

So the metrics registry is always going to be global? As I didn't find any call for the second constructor. So I can't specify registry to use?

I know if do :

```
  Metrics.globalRegistry.config().meterFilter(
            new MeterFilter() {
                @Override
                public DistributionStatisticConfig configure(Meter.Id id, DistributionStatisticConfig config) {
                   ...
                }
            });
```

**it will work, but this is not Spring way. Could anyone please help to do it right with IoC?**

Comment: I don't see a question here. Perhaps you want to open a ticket with the SpringBoot team about how they are registering their filters?  I would consider saying this isn't a problem, but I could see a case where a high cardinality meter is being created and you would want to filter that creation at the global CompositeMeterRegistry.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked as expected, my bad, I was registering a filter Spring way but filter application condition which I wrote was to check the metric name, the trick is that Spring Reactor Metrics have all same name `"reactor_flow.."` name, so I was searching for something like `"myCustomName"` in that string above.

**To distinguish flow metrics you need to check tags instead.**

In addition to that, Spring appears to have provided percentiles for reactor flow metrics (as this is exactly what my custom Filter was doing), so the need for the filter probably is not justified anymore.

Since we are early RELEASE adopters of WebFlux and Reactor, I am not sure percentiles support was there from beginning for Reactor&WebFlux.